# Convert a string to an external class/method API in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert a string into an API call?

something like this --

```
import externalLib

class InternalLib():
     def function(param1='ext1'):
           #so I want it to call externalLib.ext1
           return externalLib.param1
```

Comment: `return getattr(externalLib, param1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `getattr`. Like so:

```
import externalLib

class InternalLib():
     def function(param1='ext1'):
           # Calls externalLib.ext1()
           # Omit the final () for externalLib.ext1
           return getattr(externalLib, param1)()
```

`getattr(object, "attribute")` is the same as `object.attribute`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getattr`. Check out [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string?rq=1) that might help you. :)